# IllegalArgumentException: AdConsent Library

Tags: android, crashlytics

I implemented AdConsent library, and I got a Crashlytics notification

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Parameter
>   specified as non-null is null: method e.c.b.d.b, parameter
>   errorDescription
>   package_id.MainActivity$checkForAdConsent$1.onConsentInfoUpdated

Stack trace:

```
package_id.MainActivity$checkForAdConsentMethod$1.onConsentInfoUpdated (Unknown Source)
com.google.ads.consent.ConsentInformation$ConsentInfoUpdateTask.onPostExecute (Unknown Source:42)
com.google.ads.consent.ConsentInformation$ConsentInfoUpdateTask.onPostExecute (Unknown Source:1)
android.os.AsyncTask.finish (AsyncTask.java:636)
android.os.AsyncTask.access$500 (AsyncTask.java:177)
android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage (AsyncTask.java:653)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5254)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:903)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

First off, Crashlytics Reports are supposed to be deobfuscated in Firebase Crashlytics console but I don't understand why I should have something like this

> method e.c.b.d.b

in my Report.

My Implementation of CheckForAdConsent:

```
private fun checkForAdConsent() {
        val consentInformation = ConsentInformation.getInstance(this)
        val publisherIds = Array(1, { "admob-pub-id" })
        consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(publisherIds, object : ConsentInfoUpdateListener {
            override fun onConsentInfoUpdated(consentStatus: ConsentStatus) {
                when (consentStatus) {
                    ConsentStatus.NON_PERSONALIZED -> loadAds(false)
                    ConsentStatus.PERSONALIZED -> loadAds(true)
                    ConsentStatus.UNKNOWN -> runOnUiThread() { displayConsentForm() }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onConsentInfoUpdated, Consent Status = ${consentStatus.name}")
            }

            override fun onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo(errorDescription: String) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo - $errorDescription")
            }
        })
    }
```

The errors occur on android 5.1 - 4.1.2